# MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: No space left on dev

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I created a Redis cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves. Each of the node has at least 20 maps with 2 million key-value each.

I'm trying to insert data in billions, after inserting certain millions of data facing below error while inserting more data

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: MISCONF Errors writing to the AOF file: 
    No space left on device
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:222)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hset(Jedis.java:606)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster$30.execute(JedisCluster.java:380)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster$30.execute(JedisCluster.java:377)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.runWithRetries(JedisClusterCommand.java:119)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisClusterCommand.run(JedisClusterCommand.java:30)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster.hset(JedisCluster.java:382)
    at RedisClusterImport.main(RedisClusterImport.java:31)
```

maxmemory is not set and its default which means it will use whole system memory if I'm not wrong.
Please help me if anyone knows the solution for this.

Comment: The error generally means that you ran out of disk space, and is reported by your OS to Redis, and then by Redis to you.